# Pycharm project bug after cloning from VCS: "nothing to show" in interpreters

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, pipenv

I have a project for which I set up a **pipenv** environment with Python 3.7. It worked fine until I **cloned** from master in VCS. I have done this many times before for the same project, but my last clone messed something up:

- All my project files seem to be out of the project:

  The yellow background on my project files show that they are considered external to the project. (Had to black out some words because of company rules).

  [image: The yellow background on my files show that they are considered external to the project]
- My build/debug configurations show nonsense (there's a configuration for each file, things that I have never done).
- The **Python interpreter** in the options says *"Nothing to show"*:

  As you can see, my Python interpreter does not display, and I cannot add one either.

  [image: Python interpreter does not display, cannot add a new one either]

---

I tried opening another project which uses venv, and it worked perfectly fine.

From what I found, some other people have had this problem but I never found any fix, except someone who said the bug disappeared when rebooting. I tried but it didn't work.

**My theory** is that after cloning, my files are now out of the current project. This is why pipenv wouldn't work, and I couldn't add a Python interpreter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior is under investigation now, please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48492

A workaround is to delete `.idea` folder in the project and reopen it in PyCharm.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, I hope this can help other people until JetBrains solves it.